# Determine connection state

Tags: android

I am trying  to determine if my current connection state is WIFI or Cell network (3g/2g... etc)
I am using SDK 1.5.

Tried couple of technics not realy working.

Any working suggestions?

Thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 1):

I think NetworkInfo has a field for this.

Check out `getTypeName()` Return a human-readable name describe the type of the network, for example "WIFI" or "MOBILE", go check out [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getTypeName())

Answer (score 1):

i forget the sdk version ,if you look for"WIFI" or "MOBILE",  you may ues
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile 
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi 
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();

if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) { 
    //mobile 
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) { 
    //wifi 
}

Comment: i tried that once, and i got mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED as true both cases(wifi and without wifi)

is that possible?